# Prove that a language does not many one reduce to its complement

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability

I am trying to prove that an undecidable language $L$ is not many one reducible to its complement.

The problem goes as follows:
Formally prove that  $L \not\leq_m \overline{L}$ for any undecidable $L$. ($\overline L$ is also denoted $L^c$.)

How would I go about proving this?  I am unsure how to prove mapping reducibility, especially regarding any language.

I know I will need to use reduction here somehow.  And I know that I will need to use the properties of L (like the fact that it is undecidable).  Would I have to create a machine  and ′ such that  halts iff ′?

Comment: For the future, instead of deleting and re-posting your question, we'd prefer that you edit it based on the feedback you've received.

Comment: I'll repeat feedback that I gave before.  We're not looking for questions that are just the statement of an exercise-style task and a request for us to tell you how to solve it.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? Did you try working through some examples? Do you know any examples of undecidable languages, and have you tried proving it for them? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: If you are unsure how to prove mapping reducibility between two specific languages, before attempting this exercise, I suggest that you study mapping reducibility and read some examples of such reductions.  Any good textbook on this topic should have coverage of that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to answer this question you need to use concept of Turing degrees.

We know that if L is undecidable, Then there is some least k which L is recursively enumerabe using a Turing machine with an oracle for 0^{k} but L is not decidable with this oracle.

We use this fact to show that L' s complement is not many one reducible to L:

Let's say《To get a contradiction》 that L' s complement is many one reducible to L. So there is some computable function f which:

For all x

x belongs to L' s complement if and only if f(x) belongs to L.

Now, Let's use the fact that for any 2 languages A and B, if A is many one reducible to B and B is recursively enumerabe using an oracle for C, Then A is recursively enumerabe using an oracle for C.

So, because L' s complement is many one reducible to L and L is recursively enumerabe using an oracle for 0^{k}, we can deduct that L's complement is recursively enumerabe using an oracle for 0^{k}.

But this way we can conclude that L is decidable using an oracle for 0^{k}. Which contradicts our assumption which states "L is not decidable using an oracle for 0^{k}."