# Reduction from $\mathsf{ALL}_{\mathsf{TM}}$ to it's complement

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, undecidability, recursively-enumerable

I'd like to know if there's a reduction $\mathsf{ALL}_{\mathsf{TM}}\leq_{m}\overline{\mathsf{ALL}_{\mathsf{TM}}}$ where of course $\mathsf{ALL}_{\mathsf{TM}}=\left\{ \left\langle M\right\rangle \mid\mathsf{L}\left(M\right)=\Sigma^{*}\right\} $

All attempts I've tried failed - if for example I try to define the reduction by switching the accept state and the reject state, the construction fails because it doesn't take care of the case where the machine doesn't halt.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is no. There is no such a reduction.

Your question is actually can be answered using theorem which is stated here:

[Prove that a language does not many one reduce to its complement](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/154941/159462)